# Highcharts column chart formatting

Tags: highcharts

We have been given a mock up:

[image]

Im looking around on highcharts but i dont see if i can do this. The thing im looking for specifically is a custom string/value above the x axis category.

As far as i can see the x axis category is just an array of strings, so i cant use html or anything even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> HTML in Highcharts
>
> Texts and labels in Highcharts are given in HTML, but as the HTML is
> parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported. The following
> tags are supported: `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<em>`, `<br/>`, `<span>`. Spans can
> be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS that is
> shared with SVG is handled.
>
> Most places where text is handled in Highcharts, it is also followed
> by an option called useHTML. When this is true, the text is laid out
> as HTML on top of the chart. This allows for full HTML support and can
> be a good idea if you want to add images in your labels, tables in
> your tooltip etc.

So, you can use HTML tags in categories array, for example:

```
  xAxis: {
    ...,
    categories: [
      '<span style="font-size: 16px; color: red;">-22.5%</span><br>CLIENT<br>CALLS',
      ...
    ]
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kLu7rtea/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML